# Does $\int _0^{\infty }\left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)^2dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two continuous functions at $[0,\infty)$.

Also, $\int _0^{\infty }f^2\left(x\right)^{ }dx$ $\;\;$and $\;\;\int _0^{\infty }g^2\left(x\right)^{ }dx\;\;$ converges.

Does $\int _0^{\infty }\left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)^2dx$ converge  ?

I tried to assume that it doesn't converge. and I got to :

$\:\int _0^{\infty \:}\left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)^2dx\:\le\:\int _0^{\infty }f^2\left(x\right)dx\:+\int _0^{\infty \:}g^2\left(x\right)dx\:+\:2\int _0^{\infty \:}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\left|g\left(x\right)\right|dx$

We know that the first two addents converges. What about the left addent ?

Comment: Just use the schwartz inequality. $\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x) dx \leq \sqrt{\int_0^\infty |f^2(x)| dx} \sqrt{\int_0^\infty |g^2(x)| dx}$ Assuming $f$ and $g$ are real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality,
$$\left|f(x)\right|\cdot\left|g(x)\right|\leq\frac{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}{2}$$
So $\int_0^\infty\left|f(x)\right|\left|g(x)\right|dx$ converges.

Comment: that's correct ?
$\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\left|g\left(x\right)\right|=\sqrt{\left|f^2\left(x\right)\right|\left|g^2\left(x\right)\right|}\:\le \:\:\:\frac{f^2\left(x\right)+g^2\left(x\right)}{2}\:\:$

Comment: $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2\geq 0\implies ab\leq \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}$